# Connecting with socket gives ConnectionRefusedError

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have just begun to learn the Socket library in Python. I am following a tutorial, but in one of the very first examples I get an error when I try to run it.

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close
```

At first I wrote it in by hand, but, after getting the error message after several reviews I directly copied the text into Python and ran it. But for some reason I still get this Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elikerr\Documents\socketFirstServer.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Can someone please elaborate on what is going wrong.
This is the [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm) I'm following.
I  have checked some of the answers on Stack Exchange, but none of them seem to answer my question, or, if they do I do not know enough about Sockets to know what I am looking for.

Comment: Is port 12345 open?

Comment: How do I check whether the port is open or not?

Comment: Have you written a server that listens on that port, and is it running before you run the client? If not, what aree you expecting to connect to?

Comment: As I've said. I am quite new to this. I actually have no idea what you guys are talking about. So, sorry if I can't answer what your along. Would anyone be able to write something for me to run to check if the port is open, or point me in the direction of where to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only posted the client code I will assume you went ahead to writing the client before setting up the server.

You need to put the following code in file (server.py) and run it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   c.send(b'Thank you for connecting')   # Send bytes
   c.close()                # Close the connection
```

Now verify the server is running like so:

```
C:\Users\pp9x2>netstat -an | findstr 12345
TCP    192.168.56.1:12345     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Now use the exact code you posted and everything should just work.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this later.

Comment: Also, do you need to be connected to the internet for this to work?

Comment: No you do not need internet. You can do it without any networking equipment since you are or will be running both the server and client on the same machine. Check out this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) its short and might clear some things up. Anyways do not forget to accept my answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much @preezzzy although when it got to `c.send("Thank you for connecting")` I received an error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It has to do with you using python3 while your tutorial is for python2. I totally missed that you tagged the question  _python-3.x_. I am not at all sure, since I don't have python 3 installed but try prefacing the string with the letter b. `c.send(b'Thank you for connecting')`